# How does the noise texture keep it's values between a 0 to 1 range

Tags: texturing

When using both the fac output and the color output (which is the same as three different fac outputs in RGB) the values somehow are always between a 0 to 1 value range. If we use a reguralar perlin noise like the musgrave texture in Blender we see that for high detail values the output values quickly go above 1 and below 0. So the noise texture, which like the musgrave texture also evaluates a perlin noise, obviously remaps the perlin noise so that it always stays in the 0 to 1 range.

Could somebody please explain how the noise texture does that and link the source code, which controls this remapping?

Comment: Looks like it just divides it by the maximum possible amplitude. [src](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/4dd1068a5789097b50eab159adc995906fa5ea84/intern/cycles/kernel/shaders/node_noise.h#L87)

Comment: Wait how did you figure that out?

Comment: Cause I just found that out simultaneously XD

Comment: But do you know why Blender seems to have the same code in multiple locations? Because I found it in a completely different folder

Comment: There are at least two implementations of nodes; Eevee, that uses OpenGL and is written in GLSL, and Cycles that uses OSL. For simple nodes I generally I find Cycles easier to understand. They differ for things like Principled (Eevee uses an approximation IIUC).

Comment: In the source code you linked it uses a "noise" function, which is not declared in that file do you know where it is?

Comment: No. (more characters so this passes the character limit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is actually only that for example `Musgrave Texture` initializes perlin noise as *signed integer*, and the `Noise Texture` as *unsigned integer*.

Therefore only the range from $-1$ to $1$ or $0$ - $1$ changes at the base.

The following example illustrates this a bit better:

[image]

On the left, the values have simply been mapped to a new range using the `Map Range` node, and on the right is the normal *Noise Texture* (the contrast here is just to make the result stand out more).

You can find the corresponding places in the source code here:

**Musgrave Texture:**

- [class MusgraveFunction](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/nodes/shader/nodes/node_shader_tex_musgrave.cc#L126)
- [float musgrave_multi_fractal](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/blenlib/intern/noise.cc#L747)

**Noise Texture:**

- [class NoiseFunction](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/nodes/shader/nodes/node_shader_tex_noise.cc#L84)
- [float perlin_fractal_template](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/blenlib/intern/noise.cc#L533)

Comment: Wow, this again is in a completely different location than what scurest and I found.

Comment: Small correction: musgrave node also doesn't divide by maximal amplitude

Comment: @tempdevnova Yes, in further consequence these function differently, you are absolutely right, but the decisive factor is primarily the basis with which the calculation is started.

Comment: @quellenform Sorry. Am I correct for saying this: The actual range of Perlin Noise is [-1,1], but in Blender, the range is remapped to [0,1] (for whatever reason) by using a Map Range (aka Linear Interpolation) function?

Answer (score 2):

Scurest found the corresponding source code, linked in his comment.

Apart from that I also found the source code in question in a different folder:

https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/dfb8c90324c018068f12ca41543c3c311dff6d21/source/blender/gpu/shaders/material/gpu_shader_material_fractal_noise.glsl#L29

So, yeah basically it just divides by the maximal possible amplitude.

Comment: Sorry. Am I correct for saying this: The actual range of Perlin Noise is [-1,1], but in Blender, the range is remapped to [0,1] (for whatever reason) by using a Map Range function? The highest upvotes answer mentioned Map Range (aka Linear Interpolation).